# pre-commit yapf fails on file included in yapfignore

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com, yapf

One of the pre-commit hooks set up in the repo is yapf (`.pre-commit-config.yaml`):

```yaml
repos:
# Note: the YAPF config is found in `.style.yapf` and `.yapfignore`
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-yapf
    rev: v0.29.0
    hooks:
    -   id: yapf
```

Whenever I make changes to a file that is included in `.yapfignore` and run the pre-commit hook, the hook fails:

```
pre-commit run yapf                                                                                                                                                                                         
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to ****************
yapf.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: yapf
- exit code: 1

yapf: Input filenames did not match any python files
```

Anyone know how to avoid yapf failing on the files included in the `.yapfignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the cause of the problem is that yapf treats files that are in the `.yapfignore` as if they're files that don't exist so you'll get a:

```
yapf: Input filenames did not match any python files
```

Error if you run yapf against any file in the `.yapfignore` file. To get around this problem in `pre-commit`, I added an existing python file not in `.yapfignore` as an argument so yapf always has a file to run against.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are happening in your output and the behaviours you're seeing so I'll explain them separately:

```
$ pre-commit run yapf                                                                                                                                                                                         
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to ****************
```

this output here indicates that `pre-commit` took your un-staged changes and discarded them, likely not showing what you expect.  you probably want `pre-commit run yapf --all-files` when demonstrating what's going on

on to the actual question.

pre-commit doesn't know about implementation details of whatever tool you're using (and to an extent, `yapf` doesn't either!)

when a file is in `.yapfignore` and you pass it to `yapf` it acts as if it doesn't exist (which is very strange!)

```
$ tail -n999 hello_wat.py .yapfignore 
==> hello_wat.py <==
x =     5+  4

==> .yapfignore <==
hello*.py

$ yapf hello_wat.py 
yapf: Input filenames did not match any python files
```

what you probably want to do is utilize `pre-commit`'s [`exclude`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-exclude) so that the files are never passed to `yapf` at all!  taking my example (you didn't share your `.yapfignore` or a minimal case to go off of)

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-yapf
    rev: v0.29.0
    hooks:
    -   id: yapf
        exclude: ^hello\.*\.py$
```

now yapf won't run against `hello*.py`!

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit.

Comment: This approach is great! But it doesn't really scale when there are a lot of files in the `.yapfignore` :/. Unless there is a way to programmatically include all files in the yapfignore in `pre-commit`'s `exclude`?  (thank you for creating an awesome tool btw)

Comment: I would just ditch your `.yapfignore` personally -- though it shouldn't be too hard to write a multiline regex which captures the same thing: https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions